# C replace special character

Tags: c

I would like to replace the `'` character with `\'` I use the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int i, j = 0;
    char str[] = "HELLO'All";
    char pch[128] = { 0 };

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        if (str[i] == '\'') {
            pch[j] = '\\';
            printf(" pch[%d] = *%c* \n", j, pch[j]);
            pch[++j] = str[i];
            continue;          
        }
        pch[j++] = str[i];
    }
    printf("pch = *%s* \n", pch);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the result: `pch = *HELLO\All*`
Expected result: `pch = *HELLO\'All*`
What is missing in my code?

Comment: What string are you expecting as a result?

Comment: Try to run your program step-by-step through a debugger.

Comment: @Acorn I think he's expecting `HELLO\'All`, i.e. insertion of a backslash before the single quote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you miss an increment of `j`

Try like this

```
  pch[j++]='\\';
  printf(" pch[%d] = *%c* \n",j-1,  pch[j-1]);
  pch[j++]=str[i];
```

or like this

```
  pch[j]='\\';
  printf(" pch[%d] = *%c* \n",j,  pch[j]);
  ++j;
  pch[j++]=str[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to replace the apostrophe (`'`) in the original string `str` simply put

```
str[i] = '\\';
```

in the `if` block starting with

```
if(str[i]=='\'')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Only small change is there. Since its a char array, u can't add string.

```
int main()
{
    int i,j=0;
    char str[] = "HELLO'All";
    char pch[128]={0};

    for(i=0; i< strlen(str); i++)
    {
      if(str[i]=='\'')
      {
        pch[j]='\\';
        j++;
        pch[j]='\'';
        pch[++j]=str[i];
        continue;          
    }
    pch[j++]=str[i];
  }
  printf("pch = *%s* \n", pch);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to increment `j` a second time when you insert the `\`.

Here is a corrected and simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int i, j;
    char str[] = "HELLO'All";
    char pch[128];

    for (i = j = 0, str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (str[i] == '\'') {
            pch[j++] = '\\';
        }
        pch[j++] = str[i];
    }
    pch[j] = '\0';
    printf("pch = *%s*\n", pch);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you should also replace `\` with `\\` and you should check if the destination array is large enough (not a problem with the posted code, but a more general routine would need to compare `j` to the size of `pch`.